# Array Index out of bound 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array where no. of rows is 1 and no. of columns is > 1.

```
double[][] T = new double[1][24];
System.out.println(T[1].length);
```

But when i print the length of the columns, its says the index is out of bounds.

but when i print the following,

```
System.out.println(T[0].length);
```

I get the result as 24. But shouldn't T[0] should be equal to 1 and T[1] be equal to 24?
Why am I getting this error? 
I suppose, java considers the above array as 1D array since it has only one row. but I need it to be a 2D array for further processes. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array indices are 0-based.

If your array length is `1` (for the 1st dimension here), then you can only reference element `0`.

In other words:

- The **declaration** states the desired **size** (`1` here)
- The element **reference** states the desired **0-based index** (`0` here)

Answer (score 2):

`Array` indices start from `0`.

Your array length is 1, so `T[0]` is a valid index but `T[1]` is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(T[0].length);
```

is correct. Because Array index starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

**Array is zero based** so when `double[][] T = new double[1][24];`
you created a 2d array first dimension is 1 and the second is 24 so that's 1*24 Array

So `System.out.println(T[1].length);` gave you `java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception` As arrays are zero based

if you wrote this `double[][] T = new double[3][24];`  you got 3*24 Array :-

```
System.out.println(T[0].length);//24
System.out.println(T[1].length);//24
System.out.println(T[2].length);//24
System.out.println(T[3].length);//java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array` index starts from 0.

```
double[][] T = new double[1][24];
```

which can be also declared as follows:

```
double[][] T = new double[1][];
T[0] = new double[24];
```

Answer (score 1):

imagine matrix of 1X24. you don't have 2nd column so obvious it will through nullpointerException.

Answer (score 1):

In Java/Android and many other languages this is how is declared

```
matrix[numRows][numColumns]
```

And since `Array` indices start from `0` you need to be carefull to be sure that you are accessing a single value

```
x = matrix[0][1]
```

Or if you are accesing the first row (as a single dimension array)

```
x = matrix[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array index start with 0 not 1.

If your array length is 1  then you can start from 0.
so T[0] is a valid index but T[1] is not