# 2D array String split error

Tags: java, arrays

So basically my program takes a text file and reads the file and splits it into a 2D array (Textfile: http://pastebin.com/6ACSUL20).    I pass the name of the text file in the command line.  However, when I run my program I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which leads me to believe that the program did not split the text file correctly.  Pointing me to every method that contains `Integer.parseInt(titanic[i][1])`   Any help would be appreciated.

```
package testtitanic;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


public class Titanic {
    String[][] titanic;

    public Titanic(String[] args){
        try{
            File text = new File(args[0]);

            //turns the txt file into a string
            String content = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            //creates array and breaks up by new lines
            String[] rows = content.split("\n");

            // creates 2D array
            this.titanic = new String[rows.length][];

            // fills 2D array
            for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                this.titanic[i] = rows[i].split("\\t");
            }// end for loop


        }// end try

        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());

        }// end catch method


    }// end fill method


    public void menu(){
        System.out.println("*******Welcome to the Titanic Statistical Application**************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the question you want answered. Enter 'Q' to quit program:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. How many passengers were on the Titanic?");
        System.out.println("2. What percent of passengers perished on the Titanic?");
        System.out.println("3. What percent of passengers survived the sinking of the Titanic?");
        System.out.println("4. What percentage of passengers survived for each of the three classes?");
        System.out.println("5. What specific passengers who were less than 10 years old survived the sinking of the titanic?");
        System.out.println("6. For each letter in the alphabet, how many passengers last names started with that letter?");
        System.out.println("7. How many females and males were on the Titanic?");
        System.out.println("Q. Quit the program");
                }

    public void getPassengerNumber(){
        int num = titanic.length;
        System.out.println("There were " + num + " passengers on the Titanic.");
    }//end method

    public void getPerishedPercent(){
        int num = titanic.length;
        int perished = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(titanic[i][1]);
            if(x == 0){
                ++perished;

            }// end if
        }// end for
        double percent = (perished / num) * 100;
        System.out.println("The percentage perished on the Titanic is: " + percent);

    }// end method

    public void getPerishedSurvived(){
        int num = titanic.length;
        int survived = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(titanic[i][1]);
            if(x == 1){
                ++survived;

            }// end if
        }// end for
        double percent = (survived / num) * 100;
        System.out.println("The percentage survived on the Titanic is: " + percent);

    }// end method

    public void getClassPercentage(){
        int firstClass = 0;
        int secondClass = 0;
        int thirdClass = 0;
        int num = titanic.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < titanic.length; i++ ){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(titanic[i][0]);
            if(x == 1){
                ++firstClass;
            }// end iff
            if(x == 2){
                ++secondClass;
            }
            if(x == 3){
                ++thirdClass;
            }
        }// end for
      double firstpercent = (firstClass / num) * 100;
      double secondpercent = (secondClass / num) * 100;
      double thirdpercent = (thirdClass / num) * 100;

      System.out.println("Percent Survived for Firstclass is: " + firstpercent);
      System.out.println("Percent Survived for Secondclass is: " + secondpercent);
      System.out.println("Percent Survived for ThirdClass is: " + thirdpercent);

    }// end method

    public void getAge() {
        int num = titanic.length;
        int age = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++ ){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(titanic[i][4]);
            if(x < 10){
                System.out.println(titanic[i][2]);
            }
        }// end for loop


    }// end method

    public void getLetters(){
        for(char a = 'A'; 'Z' <= a; a++ ){
           int temp = 0; 
           for(int i = 0; i < titanic.length; i++){
               char x = titanic[i][2].charAt(0);
               if(x == a){
                   ++temp;
               }// end if
            System.out.println(a + ": There are " + temp + " passengers that have this letter to start as their last name.");

           }// end inner
        } // end outer


    }// end method

    public void getGender(){
        int male = 0;
        int female = 0;
        int num = titanic.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            if(titanic[i][3].equals("female")){
                ++female;
            }// end if
            if(titanic[i][3].equals("male")){
                ++male;
            }// end if
        }// end for

        System.out.printf("There were %d females and %d males on the titanic \n", male, female);
    }// end method


}//end class Titanic
```

Using this class to call

```
package testtitanic;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Joe
 */
public class TestTitanic {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.now();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y = 1;
        Titanic data = new Titanic(argv);

        while(y == 1){
        data.menu();
        char x = input.next().charAt(0);
        switch (x){
            case '1':
                data.getPassengerNumber();
                break;
            case '2':
                data.getPerishedPercent();
                break;
            case '3':
                data.getPerishedSurvived();
                break;
            case '4':
                data.getClassPercentage();
                break;
            case '5':
                data.getAge();
                break;
            case '6':
                data.getLetters();
                break;
            case '7':
                data.getGender();
                break;
            case 'Q':
                y = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input to exit, be sure to input a capital Q.");

        }// end switch



        }// end while loop











        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.now();
        Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(startTime,endTime);
        double time = timeElapsed.toMillis() * 1000;
        System.out.println("Thanks for running this program the total time elapsed is: " + time + " seconds");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Index out of bound 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671757/array-index-out-of-bound-2d-array)

Comment: found the problem.... I had an extra blank line at the end of the text file... ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, but I hardcoded the filename in the Titanic constructor. Are you sure you're passing it a filename?

Can you post the stack trace? Is the array index out of bounds on argv?

You don't need to guess where the index is out of bounds is. The stack trace will tell you the exact line.

Comment: Yeah its being passed a file name.  The program partially works.  However, when it tries to call the 2D array of titanic it says out of bounds which leads me to believe that it didn't create the 2D array correctly.